# copying from one excel to other using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I need to copy information from one excel file to other using VBA. Code makes new workbook in certain destination (*C:\Users\eliza_000\Desktop\aaa*) for whole sheet (*inv*) but I need only range A1:E32 in the new workbook. 
Here is the code what I use to copy all sheet

```
Sub SaveInvWithNewName()

Dim NewFN As Variant
'Copy Invoice to a new workbook
ActiveSheet.Copy
NewFN = "C:\Users\eliza_000\Desktop\aaa\inv" & Range("E6").Value & ".xlsx"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs NewFN, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
ActiveWorkbook.Close


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider:

```
Sub dural()
    ActiveSheet.Copy
    Rows("33:1048576").Delete
    Columns("F:xfd").Delete
End Sub
```

Adjust if you are using a version of Excel pre-2007.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
Dim WB As Workbook
Dim WB2 As Workbook
Dim NewFN As String

Set WB = ThisWorkbook
Set WB2 = Workbooks.Add(1)

WB.ActiveSheet.Range("A1:E32").Copy WB2.Sheets(1).Range("a1")

NewFN = "C:\Users\eliza_000\Desktop\aaa\inv" & Range("E6").Value & ".xlsx"
NewFN = "C:\temp\stuff.xlsx"
WB2.SaveAs NewFN, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
WB2.Close
```